# Unable to Connect to MySQL Database in Python Flask App

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working on a Python Flask web application, and I'm having trouble connecting to my MySQL database. I've configured the database settings, but when I try to run the app, I get a connection error. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy for database integration.

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(**name**)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:password@localhost/db_name'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

## ... (rest of the code)

Error Messages: OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

I've double-checked my database credentials, ensured that the MySQL server is running, and verified that I can connect using a MySQL client. I also tried changing the localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the URI.

Comment: Before you comment that the error message comes from flask and not from mysql command line: this error is raised by the **client**, not by mysql. The connection does not even get to mysql. The solution is not client dependent either, you need to find out and set the connection parameters. Check your mysql client's connection parameters and replicate those if you can connect with mysql client - provided the client runs on the same machine as flask.